# Ember.js - Dynamic Route Logic Based On Authentication

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to work out how to do the following:

**Situation: User opens website.com**

**A)** If user is logged in, he is shown the "welcome template".

**B)** If user is not logged in, he is shown the "login template".

I don't want to URL in the browser to change, it should stay as website.com for both outcomes.

How can I get this route setup?

Comment: what is wrong with a /login route, if the entire template is going to change anyway?

Comment: Nothing, this is just something I've been asked to do.

Comment: I should also add that the "login" template also acts are the homepage for the product. 

Example: Facebook.com, you get a homepage is not logged in, the news feed if you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an if statement.  You'd need to put the isNotLoggedIn logic on the appropriate controller (probably application).

```
{{#if isNotLoggedIn}}
  {{render 'login'}}
{{/if}}
```

I do agree with Grapho though, this is an anti-pattern in Ember (where a url represents what you will see), and doesn't do a good job of separating your concerns (single responsibility).  But if you are being told to do it and have no say in the matter.

Comment: if i remember that embercast correctly, there is a block of logic after the ajax post() method where you can handle success and fail response from the server.  that is where the session token is set up, and *probably* where you would toggle the "isNotLoggedIn" property as well.

Comment: Thanks kingpin2k and Grapho. I have had a word with the client and explained that is goes against design patterns in not only Ember but also undermines the whole point of URLS!